Can I make the browser default handler run before the event propagates?
The browser does not process keystrokes in a textbox (<input type="text">) until after all JS event handlers are finished.
In my app, though, I have a textbox nested inside an outer widget. The outer widget is not aware of the textbox's existence, but I want to block it from processing keystrokes if the textbox is able to handle the same keystrokes. So I want to do something like this:
function onInputKeyDown(e) {
  const textbox = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
  const selStart = textbox.selectionStart, selEnd = textbox.selectionEnd;
  const content = textbox.textContent;

  e.invokeDefault() // doesn't exist

  if (selStart !== textbox.selectionStart || selEnd !== textbox.selectionEnd
      || content !== textbox.textContent)
    e.stopPropagation();
}

I tried simulating "invokeDefault" with e.preventDefault(); e.target.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', e)) but it turns out that dispatchEvent doesn't cause default behavior, it just calls event handlers (the current event handler is re-entered) so the text field doesn't change. Is there another way?

Yes. Flip it around:
function onInputKeyDown(e) {
    if (e.isTrusted) { // ignore synthetic events
        const textbox = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
        const selStart = textbox.selectionStart, selEnd = textbox.selectionEnd;
        const content = textbox.textContent;
        
        // Stop propagation to wait until the browser's default handler
        // has processed the key and updated the text field. Then, if the
        // text field has not changed, "resume" propagation with 
        // `dispatchEvent`. The new event will be "untrusted" so the 
        // browser's default processing will not happen again.
        e.stopPropagation();
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (selStart === textbox.selectionStart
                && selEnd === textbox.selectionEnd
                && content === textbox.textContent) {
                textbox.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', e as any));
            }
        });
    }
}

